# How Do I Set WSABUF.buf For Text And Bin Buffer?

Tags: c++, http, winsock, memcpy

I'm refactoring the code to not use std::vector<byte>. How do I make that happen?

Somehow, WSASend() prefers to have WSABUF.buf pointing to a std::vector<byte> for it to work for image files (.jpg, .png, etc).

During testing, image/* mimetypes return net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH.

```
byte* HttpResponse::GetResponse2(ULONG *len)
{
    DWORD dwThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();
    char *buffer = (char*)malloc(DATA_BUFSIZE);
    memset(buffer, 0, DATA_BUFSIZE);

    std::vector<byte> binbuffer = m_sbResponse;

    std::string ctstr;
    ctstr.assign(contenType.begin(), contenType.end());
    size_t siz = binbuffer.size();
    std::string ssiz = std::to_string(siz);

    strcpy_s(buffer, DATA_BUFSIZE, resp_ok);
    strcat_s(buffer, DATA_BUFSIZE, "\n");
    strcat_s(buffer, DATA_BUFSIZE, "Date: ");
    strcat_s(buffer, DATA_BUFSIZE, "May 10, 2015");
    strcat_s(buffer, DATA_BUFSIZE, "\n");
    strcat_s(buffer, DATA_BUFSIZE, "Content-Type: ");
    strcat_s(buffer, DATA_BUFSIZE, ctstr.c_str());
    strcat_s(buffer, DATA_BUFSIZE, "\n");
    strcat_s(buffer, DATA_BUFSIZE, "Content-Length: ");
    strcat_s(buffer, DATA_BUFSIZE, ssiz.c_str());
    strcat_s(buffer, DATA_BUFSIZE, "\n");
    strcat_s(buffer, DATA_BUFSIZE, "\n");

    int bufsiz = strlen(buffer) + binbuffer.size() + 1;
    byte* buffer2 = (byte*)malloc(bufsiz);
    memset(buffer2, 0, bufsiz);
    strcpy_s((char*)buffer2, strlen(buffer)+1, buffer);
    int n = strlen((char*)buffer2);

    std::vector<byte>::iterator it;
    for (it = binbuffer.begin(); it != binbuffer.end(); it++)
    {
        byte b = *it;
        buffer2[n++] = b;
    }

    *len = strlen((char*)buffer2);

    return buffer2;
}
```

Is there a property I need to set for WSA* to work with what I'm trying to do?

The [file](https://github.com/MagnusTiberius/iocphttpd/blob/505ec9b238fae6f006b64495d2157bb0605c431c/iocphttpl/HttpResponse.cpp) sits in a [repository](https://github.com/MagnusTiberius/iocphttpd/tree/505ec9b238fae6f006b64495d2157bb0605c431c).

Comment: What is the actual problem? There is no issue with using `std::vector<byte>` as long as it stays alive until `WSASend()` is done accessing it.  And `WSABUF` knows nothing about `vector`, only `char*`, so you can assign it any valid memory address you want, even from a `vector`.

Comment: I need to do a comparison for buffer ops using C and C++ containers. I have already implemented a working version using C++ containers, the other one should be limited to C, mostly memcpy, memmove, strcpy and strcat funcs. Somehow, the second one is not coming to me so easily.

Comment: The problem is when the code reads in a jpg file, it ends up truncated in the content part of the response.

Comment: Basically, it has two buffers, a text and bin buffer. Somehow I can't merge the two buffers into WSABUF.buf

Comment: Not surprising, because you are treating the binary buffer as if it were a null-terminated string, which it is not. Think about what `strlen(buffer2)` is going to return when `buffer2` contains binary null bytes in it.  You end up returning a truncated `len` value to the caller. At the very least, you need to change `n = strlen(buffer2)` to `n = strlen(buffer)`, and change `*len = strlen(buffer2)` to `*len = bufsiz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something more like this instead:

```
byte* HttpResponse::GetResponse2(ULONG *len)
{
    *len = 0;

    std::ostringstream oss;            
    oss << resp_ok << "\n"
    oss << "Date: " << "May 10, 2015" << "\n";
    oss << "Content-Type: " << contenType << "\n";
    oss << "Content-Length: " << m_sbResponse.size() << "\n";
    oss << "\n";

    std::string s = oss.str();

    int bufsiz = s.length() + m_sbResponse.size();
    byte* buffer2 = (byte*) malloc(bufsiz);
    if (buffer2)
    {
        std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), buffer2);
        std::copy(m_sbResponse.begin(), m_sbResponse.end(), &buffer2[s.length()]);
        *len = bufsiz;
    }

    return buffer2;
}
```

That being said, I would strongly suggest not returning a `byte*`.  Your `GetResponse()` method takes an output `std::vector<byte>` as a parameter, you really should stick with that model:

```
void HttpResponse::GetResponse2(std::vector<byte> *pv)
{
    pv->clear();

    std::ostringstream oss;            
    oss << resp_ok << "\n"
    oss << "Date: " << "May 10, 2015" << "\n";
    oss << "Content-Type: " << contenType << "\n";
    oss << "Content-Length: " << m_sbResponse.size() << "\n";
    oss << "\n";

    std::string s = oss.str();

    pv->reserve(s.length() + m_sbResponse.size());
    std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::back_inserter(*pv));
    std::copy(m_sbResponse.begin(), m_sbResponse.end(), std::back_inserter(*pv));
}
```

Comment: I got the code added and they are working, that will be used for comparing against the first.

Comment: Here is another [variant](https://gist.github.com/MagnusTiberius/d4e63c8dc4c5b19ba138) which also works.

Comment: Here is [variant #3](https://gist.github.com/MagnusTiberius/e5002530fcb1f72249e7) and the turnaround time for this code is averaging on 20 milliseconds. Fastest I got was < 1 ms. Most of it is based on C except for the vector&lt;byte&gt; in there.